# QGIS OSM baselayer zoom level on print layout size A1

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I am using an offline OSM baselayer map in QGIS and prepared a printlayout map size A1. Scale is 160000. When I have the map on 100% in the printlayout I can read the names of the cities and smaller villages on my screen. When plotting same size (A1) the map gets kind of blury and the names change to little so that I am not able to read them anymore.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Either add a basemap with a fixed scale which corresponds with the scale of your map/layout, or when exporting the map, decrease the dpi.